# Android application not launched

Tags: android

I am new in Android development.

I make a very simple application. When I run on AVD, it fails.

**Error is as follows :-**

```
[2014-03-22 22:46:43 - Calculator] ------------------------------
[2014-03-22 22:46:43 - Calculator] Android Launch!
[2014-03-22 22:46:43 - Calculator] adb is running normally.
[2014-03-22 22:46:43 - Calculator] Performing com.jhamb.calculaor.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-03-22 22:46:46 - Calculator] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Nexus4_AVD'
[2014-03-22 22:47:17 - Emulator] emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
[2014-03-22 22:47:17 - Emulator] 
[2014-03-22 22:47:17 - Calculator] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2014-03-22 22:47:17 - Calculator] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2014-03-22 22:53:27 - Calculator] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-03-22 22:53:27 - Calculator] Uploading Calculator.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-03-22 22:53:28 - Calculator] Installing Calculator.apk...
[2014-03-22 22:55:36 - Calculator] Failed to install Calculator.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2014-03-22 22:55:36 - Calculator] (null)
[2014-03-22 22:55:36 - Calculator] Launch canceled!
```

**AVD, that I am using :-**

[image]

I followed so many posts on SO. But no-one solved my problem.

I try to resolve above issue, by using below steps :-

-> I restarted adb through command line `adb kill-server adb start-server`

-> Set `wipe user data`

Please help me to solve above problem. I stuck from last 5 hours in this.

**AndroidManifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jhamb.calculaor"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.jhamb.calculaor.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**When I changed RAM to 1072 MB, then it shows below error**

```
[2014-03-22 23:56:24 - Calculator] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'nexus-4-api-19'
[2014-03-22 23:57:01 - Emulator] WARNING: Data partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
[2014-03-22 23:57:01 - Emulator] NAND: could not write file C:\Users\AMPLIF~1\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\TMP46B6.tmp, No space left on device
```

**SDK Manager**

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you post your `AndroidManifest`?

Comment: Are you by chance running out of room on your computer? That's what the error sounds like.

Comment: @kentarosu what is the meaning of this ?

Answer (score 0):

I am posting below a screenshot of how I configured my nexus 4 emulator, which works fine on my system. I hope this helps. 
Probably you just gave to little memory to your emulator: 512MB seems very low to me!

[image]

Comment: It shows me one warning, `On Windows, emulating RAM greater than 768M may fail depending on the system load.Try progressively smaller values of RAM if the emulator fails to launch`.

Comment: I don't know how it works in Windows, I am more a Linux guy. But that it does not let you give the emulator more RAM is really sad..

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is just because the emulator didn't launch quickly enough. Try re-launching without closing the emulator between each launch.